# WPF and ICUTest unit tests

Tags: wpf, testing, nunit

Hi I am evaluating ICUTest for use on a project.  My initial view is that it looks like a promising Visual testing library.  The scenario I have for using ICUTest is to start an application with a specific configuration and I expect the main application window to display based on the configuration settings.  Each unit test should start the application and then after completing it should shutdown the application gracefully.

At the moment I can get individual tests to run, but when I run multiple tests I start running into all types of threading issues.  Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to test your application.

1) The easiest (and most reusable) way is to just test your main app window like any other window.  Do your initialization after a window event (like Window.Loaded) or through the constructor (e.g. new MainWindow("myapp.config") ).

2) If initialization must be done before the window is up then you can start the app thread with code similar to the one [here](http://bit.ly/hTiPXC).

Note: in WPF, you can only start an Application once, so method (1) is preferable.

Also, make sure you wrap all your GUI related calls in an ICU.Invoke(...) block.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I couldn't get your second option to work using the latest IcuTest dll's.  I am also trying to get a prism bootstrapper to run to test various views that have been configured.  This is proving very difficult to do regardless of which of the above options that I have tried.

Comment: I think the major problem is starting the application more than once.  WPF simply won't allow it.  Can you even call the prism bootstrapper more than once?

Comment: I emailed an example project to the nxs7 support email address with a prism bootstrapper, but have not yet heard back from them